# Double Speak - Phrases that need rewording

Tags: english, metapuzzles

Each of these phrases can be reworded into a Double Speak phrase. A Double Speak phrase has two homophones together in the same phrase. For example a "Warrior's time of rest" could also be called a "Knight's Night". The thirteen phrases that need rewording are as follows:

- Unwarranted reversal.
- Untied rope.
- Cover up a detector.
- Reduce the education.
- Wedge of the clock belonging to us.
- Story about the end of a dog.
- Rabbit's fur.
- Deserve a pot.
- A pair of one-on-one battles.
- Find a purpose for some wood.
- Path taken by the bottom of a tree.
- Pilfer some metal.
- Curve on a boat.

Once you have found each of these 13 Double Speak phrases, look closely. There is a fourteenth phrase that needs rewording hiding somewhere. I'm looking for this 14th Double Speak phrase; it is the final solution to this puzzle.

Comment: Reminds me of [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unwarranted reversal.

> Undue undo

Untied rope.

> Not knot.

Cover up a detector.

> Censor sensor

Reduce the education.

> Lessen lesson

Wedge of the clock belonging to us.

> Our hour

Story about the end of a dog.

> Tail tale

Rabbit's fur

> Hare hair

Deserve a pot.

> Earn urn

A pair of one-on-one battles.

> Dual duel.

Find a purpose for some wood.

> Use yews

Path taken by the bottom of a tree.

> Root route.

Pilfer some metal.

> Steal steel

Curve on a boat

> Ark arc

The meta is given by:

> The first letters: **UNCLOTHED URSA**

...which is of course,

> **[Bare bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Bare_Bears)**.

Comment: 32 minutes! I expected it to at least reach midnight. Well played.

Comment: I had "loose noose" for untied rope. Of course that doesn't fit with the eventual meta puzzle though.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Unfortunately, "loose" and "noose" are not homophones.

Comment: @qwertyu63 I think your puzzles would benefit if you didn't explain what a "double speak phrase" is. If you just give that as the name of the phrase, people will figure out what it means.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer

Curve on a boat

> arc's ark

Rabbit's fur.

> hare's hair

Path taken by the bottom of a tree

> root's route

Answer (score 3):

This what I have so far, will update as I get more:

Unwarranted reversal.

> 

Untied rope.

> 

Cover up a detector.

> 

Reduce the education.

> 

Wedge of the clock belonging to us.

> our hour

Story about the end of a dog.

> tail's tale

Rabbit's fur.

> hare's hair

Deserve a pot.

> 

A pair of one-on-one battles.

> Dual duel

Find a purpose for some wood.

> 

Path taken by the bottom of a tree.

> root route

Pilfer some metal.

> steal steel

Curve on a boat.

> arks arc