# Double Speak Clearing House - More phrases that need rewording

Tags: english

When I was making [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59439/double-speak-phrases-that-need-rewording), I actually made far more Double Speak puzzles than I wound up combining into the resulting metapuzzle. I'd rather they not go to waste, so here they are.

As with the previous set, each of these phrases can be reworded into a Double Speak phrase. A Double Speak phrase has two homophones together in the same phrase. For example, to "Purchase a departure" could also be said as to "Buy a Bye".

- The child of a star.
- Extremely boring aircraft.
- A ship part cheaper than usual.
- Two identical fruits.
- Earn a number for coming in first.
- Created a housecleaner.
- Celebrity who's not doing anything.
- Look at the ocean.
- Run from a bug.
- Musicians who aren't allowed.
- Acceptable cab price.
- Use a pen correctly.
- Glare at the steps.
- Inheritor of the atmosphere.
- Formerly flying blade.

There is no clever metapuzzle this time. If you find all 15 Double Speak phrases, you're done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I think this is all of them...**

The child of a star.

> Son of a sun

Extremely boring aircraft.

> Plain plane

A ship part cheaper than usual.

> Sail on sale

Two identical fruits.

> Pair of pears

Earn a number for coming in first.

> Won one

Created a housecleaner.

> Maid made

Celebrity who's not doing anything.

> Idle Idol

Look at the ocean.

> See sea

Run from a bug.

> Flee from a flea

Musicians who aren't allowed.

> Banned band

Acceptable cab price.

> Fair fare

Use a pen correctly.

> Write right

Glare at the steps.

> Stare at the stairs

Inheritor of the atmosphere.

> Heir of the air

Formerly flying blade.

> Sword soared

Comment: You've got all of them right except the last one.

Comment: @qwertyu63 - no, I think I got it, I just had a mind fart typo :) fixed now.

Comment: Now you got it.

Comment: I think you have "Use a pen correctly" in the wrong order... Shouldn't it be Use a pen.... correctly.

Comment: @StianYttervik - you make a convincing argument. fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I get:

> Sun son, plain plane, sail sale, pear pair, won one, made maid, idle idol, see sea, flee flea, barred bard (?), fair fare, write right, stare (at) stair(s), air heir and soared sword.

Comment: You got all of them except "Musicians who aren't allowed".

Answer (score 2):

I'm missing a few, but:

The child of a star.

> Kidd kid?

Extremely boring aircraft.

> Plain plane.

A ship part cheaper than usual.

> 

Two identical fruits.

> Pair of pears.

Earn a number for coming in first.

> Won one.

Created a housecleaner.

> Made a maid.

Celebrity who's not doing anything.

> 

Look at the ocean.

> See the sea.

Run from a bug.

> Flee a flea.

Musicians who aren't allowed.

> Banned band.

Acceptable cab price.

> Fair fare.

Use a pen correctly.

> Write right.

Glare at the steps.

> Stare at stair.

Inheritor of the atmosphere.

> Air heir.

Formerly flying blade.

> 