# Single Speak - Twice the same word

Tags: english

I've checked out the [Double Speak](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59439/double-speak-phrases-that-need-rewording) puzzle and really liked it, and hoped to get more of it, [which I did](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59624/double-speak-clearing-house-more-phrases-that-need-rewording). My thirst has not been sated though. Because of that, I've devised a collection of 20 riddles that need some rewording. The correct answers should give the same word twice!

- A good penalty
- A tedious drilling
- Simply fair
- Departure of a fraction
- A common commander
- A reasonable noise
- Dividing silverware
- Weightless wave
- Spread a dimension
- Observe time
- Hand a token
- Save what's left
- Unpleasant grid
- A lift raiser
- Transfer a haven
- The correct direction
- Be aware of the brain
- Abandon permission
- A just market
- Make a movement

Comment: I suppose I should accept the closest answer to what I had in mind then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my picks

A good penalty

> fine fine

A tedious drilling

> boring boring

Simply fair

> just just

Departure of a fraction

> division division   ***[OP intended: part part]***

A common commander

> general general

A reasonable noise

> sound sound

Dividing silverware

> fork fork

Weightless wave

> light light

Spread a dimension

> space space

Observe time

> watch watch

Hand a token

> gift gift   ***[OP intended: pass pass]***

Save what's left

> spare spare

Unpleasant grid

> grating grating

A lift raiser

> coach coach   ***[OP intended: elevator elevator]***

Transfer a haven

> port port

The correct direction

> right right

Be aware of the brain

> mind mind

Abandon permission

> leave leave

A just market

> fair fair

Make a movement

> erect erect   ***[OP intended: cause cause]***

Comment: You got 3 of them differently from what I intended, but they still fit in, nice job!

Answer (score 6):

**Partial**

A good penalty

> Fine fine

A tedious drilling

> boring boring

Simply fair

> Just just

Departure of a fraction

> 

A common commander

> general general

A reasonable noise

> Sound sound

Dividing silverware

> 

Weightless wave

> Light light

Spread a dimension

> Plain plain

Observe time

> Watch watch

Hand a token

> 

Save what's left

> 

Unpleasant grid

> Grating grating

A lift raiser

> Elevator elevator

Transfer a haven

> Port port

The correct direction

> Right right

Be aware of the brain

> Mind mind

Abandon permission

> Leave leave

A just market

> Fair fair

Make a movement

> 

Comment: Dividing silverware could be "fork fork"?

Comment: Be aware of the brain could be "mind mind"...

Comment: One of those is not what I had in mind but fits just right with its description, well done!

Comment: I'd rather say right instead of straight.

Comment: (And fair: just, commander: general, grid: grating, market: fair)

Comment: Observe = watch?

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken thank you :)

Comment: Departure of a fraction could be a "break break" (as in, makes a break for it)

Comment: @RickvanOsta: Or part or parting? (But the "part" is already, er, part of departure, so maybe not.)

Comment: two answers > serr & cnff (rot13) ?

Comment: @MOehm Could be, I think A Lift Raiser would be a "Lift lift", so maybe the answer doesn't necessarily have to be unique to the phrase.

Comment: @RickvanOsta I think "A lift raiser" is supposed to be "Elevator Elevator"

Comment: And also "Departure of a fraction" i think is "Separation Separation"

Comment: hand a token - gift a gift?

Comment: departure of a fraction - a fourth going forth?

Comment: unpleasant grid - grating grating?

Comment: Save what's left - the answer is *Rest* *Rest*

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay or Save what's left could be helping helping. Helping, as in saving someone the trouble, and helping as in a helping of food.

Comment: correct direction = right right

Comment: make could be raise