# Single Speak - Meta Edition

Tags: english, metapuzzles

Followup to my [previous Single Speak puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59641/single-speak-twice-the-same-word), this time I decided to follow the path of the [original Double Speak puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59439/double-speak-phrases-that-need-rewording) by adding a metapuzzle. Like in the previous time, the answer to each riddle corresponds to a pair of identical words.

> Terminate the last part
>
> Talk to where it touches
>
> Moral of the fake person
>
> The breaking free of a keyboard's key
>
> Feed the doctor's assistant
>
> Follow the road
>
> Ethnic dispute
>
> Blowing into an increase in prices
>
> Look at the tick
>
> A secure lock
>
> The dirt of a planet
>
> Identify a point
>
> Printing a feeling
>
> Rotate a chance
>
> Deserving your salary

The metapuzzle is also a Single Speak puzzle, so it'll also give you two identical words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Terminate the last part

> end

Talk to where it touches

> contact

Moral of the fake person

> character

The breaking free of a keyboard's key

> escape

Feed the doctor's assistant

> nurse

Follow the road

> track

Ethnic dispute

> race

Blowing into an increase in prices

> inflation

Look at the tick

> check

A secure lock

> safe

The dirt of a planet

> earth

Identify a point

> spot (props to [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), [ngn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41034/ngn) and [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009/sid) for this one.

Printing a feeling

> impression

Rotate a chance

> turn

Deserving your salary

> earning

So the meta puzzle is:

> Props to [Richard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18979/richard) for coming up with the answer to the meta-puzzle. The first letter of each of the above solutions gives us the metapuzzle: ECCENTRIC SE SITE, which is **Puzzling Puzzling**.

Comment: Though very close, you just missed it by one answer/letter :(

Comment: I've edited the main post to explain what you missed

Comment: The answer to the decoded puzzle (in the last paragraph) makes no sense to me at all. Care to explain?

Comment: The metapuzzle is still off by one letter/answer

Comment: :( Yes, I can't work it out. Is it just the metapuzzle, or do you mean that one of the main answers is wrong, which means I have a wrong letter in the metapuzzle?

Comment: "one of the main answers is wrong, which means [you] have a wrong letter in the metapuzzle" <- this

Comment: Thanks! I can't work it out, but I've added some more thoughts on the metapuzzle in case it helps anyone else to get the right answer.

Comment: Mark seems sketchy. It's probably SPOT.

Answer (score 8):

No point in me repeating the riddles, but I have worked out the meta puzzle. The final riddle should be

> ECCENTRIC SE SITE

Which means the answer is

> Puzzling Puzzling

Comment: Aaaaahhhhhhhhh! Now I feel silly. :) Well done.

Comment: Nice job getting the metapuzzle correctly, but I would much prefer accepting an answer that contained it all together :)

Comment: I think @Tom has done the most work here so it's probably most fair for him to add this to his answer.

Comment: Thanks Richard! Have corrected my post and added your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Work in progress**

---

*Terminate the last part*

> End the end.

*Talk to where it touches*

*Moral of the fake person*

*The breaking free of a keyboard's key*

> The escape of `Escape` (thanks [@Rubio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42581595#42581595))

*Feed the doctor's assistant*

> Nurse the nurse?

*Follow the road*

> Track the track.

*Ethnic dispute*

*Blowing into an increase in prices*

> Inflation of inflation.

*Look at the tick*

> Watch the watch.

*A secure lock*

> A safe safe.

*The dirt of a planet*

> The earth of Earth.

*Identify a point*

> Spot a spot.

*Printing a feeling*

*Rotate a chance*

> Turn a turn?

*Deserving your salary*

> Earning your earnings.

---

**Word list**

> END, ?, ?, ESCAPE, NURSE, TRACK, ?, INFLATE, WATCH, SAFE, EARTH, SPOT, ?, TURN, EARNING

Answer (score 1):

```
Terminate the last part
```

> end the end

```
Talk to where it touches
```

> contact the contact

```
Moral of the fake person
```

> gnome of the gnome

```
The breaking free of a keyboard's key
```

> escape of escape

```
Feed the doctor's assistant
```

> nurse the nurse

```
Follow the road
```

> trail the trail

```
Ethnic dispute
```

> race race (?)

```
Blowing into an increase in prices
```

> bubble bubble ("inflation of inflation" from the other answer actually sounds much better)

```
Look at the tick
```

> check the check

```
A secure lock
```

> a safe safe

```
The dirt of a planet
```

> earth of the earth

```
Identify a point
```

> spot a spot

```
Printing a feeling
```

> impression of an impression

```
Rotate a chance
```

> wheel the wheel [of fortune?]; turn a turn

```
Deserving your salary
```

> earning your earning; worth your worth; rating your rating